# Cannot get Metaplex NFT collection information from metadata

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I find [this NFT](https://opensea.io/assets/solana/6c6ZeBiXhtEwM2dhx6i6rMDpU1PF1avbD7d82xmJAxvB) in the Primates collection, according to [MCC](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/5661749143571-Getting-my-Solana-collection-on-OpenSea-Understanding-the-Metaplex-Certified-Collection-standard) it should have collection information in its metadata. But when I check on [solscan](https://solscan.io/token/6c6ZeBiXhtEwM2dhx6i6rMDpU1PF1avbD7d82xmJAxvB#metadata), there's none   Why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this case Primates are not using MCC and thats why is not showing the collection on the metadata, this can happen depending on how they create the Candy Machine. You can read about this [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections), it has an image that explains NFTs with and without MCC on its onchain metadata.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that a collection can be recognized by Opensea without MCC! So how does Opensea know the colleection information? Btw the link you sent goes to "Page not found" and then navigates to MCC page. Is it the correct page to read? Thanks!

Comment: I think OpenSea teams with projects that goes well and allow them to list on OpenSea without following the standards, also the webpage is correct the idea is that you can read it and see that are NFTs that cant have a MCC attached to it